# If $f_n \to f$ , $f , f_n \in \mathcal R[a,b] $ , then is it true that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_a^bf_n=\int_a^b f$ ?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of real valued functions with domain $[a,b]$ converging pointwise to $f$ and such that each $\{f_n\}$ and $f$ is Riemann integrable in $[a,b]$ , then must it hold that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_a^bf_n=\int_a^b f$ ?

Comment: Consider $f_n=n\cdot\chi_{[0,1/n]}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose $f_n(x)=nxe^{-nx^2}$ for $x\in[0,1]$.  Clearly, for all $x\in [0,1]$, $f_n(x)\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$ and therefore

$$\int_0^1 \lim_{n \to \infty}f_n(x) dx=0$$

But, we have

$$\int_0^1 f_n(x)\,dx=\frac12 \left(1-e^{-n}\right)\to \frac12$$

and thus

$$\lim_{n\to \infty }\int_0^1 f_n(x)\,dx=\frac12 \ne \int_0^1 \lim_{n \to \infty}f_n(x) dx=0$$

---

**NOTE:**

Although the sequence $f_n(x)\to 0$ for all $x\in [0,1]$, its maximum value occurs when $f_n'(x)=(n-2n^2x^2)e^{-nx^2}=0$.

Thus, the maximum value is at $x_{max}=1\sqrt{2n}$ and is $f_n(x_{max})=\sqrt{n/2}\,e^{-1/2}\to \infty$ as $n\to \infty$.

Therefore, as $n$ gets larger, the maximum of $f_n$ occurs closer to $0$ and the peak increases without bound such that the area tends to $1/2$.

Comment: +1 Nice to see a counterexample that doesn't use indicator functions

Comment: @SimonS First, thank you!  And I agree.  This example is clean and really illustrates the point is a way that, I believe, is easier to see than examples with "contrived functions."

Comment: +1, nice example! Also, $\max f_n(x) = \sqrt{\frac{n}{2e}}$ so the sequence is not uniformly bounded.  But $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \, f_n$ is uniformly bounded and converges pointwise (but not uniformly) to $0$, so the integrals also converge to $0$.

Comment: @orangeskid Wow!  Thank you!  And you're absolutely correct.  The convergence is not uniform.  Another way to put this is that sup norm of $f_n$ does not converge.  However, that is not a necessary condition for interchanging the orders of operation here.  It is only a sufficient condition.

Comment: @Dr. MV: Yes, indeed, $\lim_{n\to \infty} \sup | f_n| = \infty$ . So, $(\sup |g_n|)_n$ bounded is a sufficient condition for the convergence of the integral, not a necessary one. However, the only  proof of sufficiency I know is using the Lebesgue dominated convergence thm for the Lebesgue integral...

Comment: @orangeskid One can prove, I believe, that if $f_n$ converges uniformly, then the interchange is valid without appeal to the DCT for the Lebesgue integral.

Comment: @Dr. MV: Correct; it's the proof when only pointwise convergence is assumed that seems difficult without Lebesgue.

Comment: Very nice and easy to understand counterexample +1

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Wow!  Thank you.  Very much appreciative.

Answer (score 1):

No, pointwise convergence does not suffice, you need a stronger form of convergence for that to be true (e.g. uniform, monotone, dominated).

Comment: Monotone convergence and dominated convergence also suffice.

Comment: You're right, I edit